# Does the pluralisation overload of QObject::tr() translate the %n to a local number?

Tags: qt, localization, translation, pluralize

There are two forms of the `QObject::tr()` function I have been using for translating strings which contain numbers:

```
tr("There are %n foo(s)", 0, foo.size());
tr("%1: %2").arg(QLocale().toString(bar.size())).arg(bar.name());
```

These account for most instances where you want a number in a string except when you want to do localisation **and** pluralisation in the same string. Of course you could break the translation up, but you have to make a guess about whether that string will break in the same places in all languages (a decision I'm not qualified to make most of the time).

The [QLocale documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlocale.html#details) states that...

> QString::arg() uses the default locale to format a number when its position specifier in the format string contains an 'L', e.g. "%L1"

... so the second form could be rewritten as ...

```
tr("%L1: %2").arg(bar.size()).arg(bar.name());
```

... and this suggests you could rewrite the first form as...

```
tr("There are %Ln foo(s)", 0, foo.size());
```

This will compile and it shows up in Linguist as a pluralisation, but does anyone know if this will also localise the number? I can't find anything which says either way in any documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will work:

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

//    QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::German));
    QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::English));

    QTranslator qtTranslator;
//    qtTranslator.load("foo_de", qApp->applicationDirPath());
    qtTranslator.load("foo_en", qApp->applicationDirPath());
    a.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);

    int foo_count = 123456;

    QString str1 = QObject::tr("There are %n foo(s)", "foo", foo_count);
    QString str2 = QObject::tr("There are %Ln foo(s)", "foo", foo_count);

    qDebug() << str1;
    qDebug() << str2;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Output if running English:

```
"There are 123456 foos"
"There are 123,456 foos"
```

Output if running German (with apologies to any actual German speakers out there):

```
"Es gibt 123456 fooen"
"Es gibt 123.456 fooen"
```

The only weird things are:

- The translator must keep the `%Ln` in both the singular and plural translations, not just the usual `%n`.
- Linguist will complain for the plural form that "Translation does not contain the necessary %n place marker." This is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The [(Qt 4.x) documentation here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/i18n-source-translation.html#handling-plurals) would seem to imply that it will both pluralize and localize since it is presented under the section heading "Handling Plurals".

The later [Qt 5.x documentation here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/i18n-source-translation.html#handling-plurals) seems to be a verbatim copy, which seems a shame as this is not a particularly well documented use of `QObject::tr(...)`.

Comment: Answer appreciated, but I'm looking for evidence.

Comment: Well the only thing that qualifies as evidence would be the source code and that's available :)

Comment: Or documentation neither of us have found, or a test case.